# Object reinitializes each time I call a function in my NEAR Smart Contract

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I have a class in an external file and I import it.
The class is instantiated into 3 objects just below the imports.

I run function call initial where I call methods to change the property of mystudent0 to absent. Then all the properties are returned and everything runs as expected.

The problem is that when I run other functions to call other class methods, the objects are initialized. To the started values.

I cannot figure out how to stop the reinitialization, so I can call other methods.

code:

```
import { storage, context, PersistentVector } from "near-sdk-as";
import { Student } from "./student";

let students = new PersistentVector<string>('student');
let currstudents = new PersistentVector<Student>('studentlist');
let mystudent0 = new Student(1,"Pete Gillan", true);
let mystudent1 = new Student(2,"John Reager", true);
let mystudent2 = new Student(3,"Mary Smith", false);

//
export function initial(): string{
        //
        let strStud1: string;
        let strStud2: string;
        let strStud3: string;
        let studentCounter: i32 = 0;
        let len: i32;
        currstudents.push(mystudent0);
        currstudents.push(mystudent1);
        currstudents.push(mystudent2);
        mystudent0.set_absent();
        strStud1 = " Student num " + mystudent0.get_studnum().toString() + " Student name: " + mystudent0.get_sname() + " present: " + mystudent0.get_present().toString() + '\n';
        strStud2 = "Student num " + mystudent1.get_studnum().toString() + " Student name: " + mystudent1.get_sname() +  " present: " + mystudent1.get_present().toString() + '\n';
        strStud3 = "Student num " + mystudent2.get_studnum().toString() + " Student name: " + mystudent2.get_sname() +  " present: " + mystudent2.get_present().toString() + '\n';
        len = currstudents.length;
        return strStud1 + strStud2 + strStud3 + " " + len.toString();
}

export function absent(): string{
    mystudent0.set_absent();
    return "absent";
}


//
export function welcomeUser(): string {
    return "Greetings " + context.sender + " .... :)"
}

export function get_name(): string{
    //let mystudent0 = new Student(1,"Pete Gillan", true);
    let strStud1: string;
    let strStud2: string;
    let strStud3: string;
    let len: i32;
    strStud1 = " Student num " + mystudent0.get_studnum().toString() + " Student name: " + mystudent0.get_sname() + " present: " + mystudent0.get_present().toString() + '\n';
    strStud2 = "Student num " + mystudent1.get_studnum().toString() + " Student name: " + mystudent1.get_sname() +  " present: " + mystudent1.get_present().toString() + '\n';
    strStud3 = "Student num " + mystudent2.get_studnum().toString() + " Student name: " + mystudent2.get_sname() +  " present: " + mystudent2.get_present().toString() + '\n';
    len = currstudents.length;
    return strStud1 + strStud2 + strStud3 + " " + len.toString();
}
```

results:

```
:~/roster-project/src/simple/assembly$ near call $CONTRACT initial --account_id $OWNER
Scheduling a call: dev-1640024016985-13984676030210.initial()
Doing account.functionCall()
Transaction Id CFhBKtxJZFt97kFNfRAE3EoXc9tvPqb6rgPMdv1atfjN
To see the transaction in the transaction explorer, please open this url in your browser
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/CFhBKtxJZFt97kFNfRAE3EoXc9tvPqb6rgPMdv1atfjN
' Student num 1 Student name: Pete Gillan present: **false**\n' +
  'Student num 2 Student name: John Reager present: true\n' +
  'Student num 3 Student name: Mary Smith present: false\n' +
  ' 6'
:~/roster-project/src/simple/assembly$  near call $CONTRACT get_name --account_id $OWNER
Scheduling a call: dev-1640024016985-13984676030210.get_name()
Doing account.functionCall()
Transaction Id 8485qqoHSp9WrjiNQKVZtzwMZsh1tE29WFwRkzfJwYLL
To see the transaction in the transaction explorer, please open this url in your browser
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/8485qqoHSp9WrjiNQKVZtzwMZsh1tE29WFwRkzfJwYLL
' Student num 1 Student name: Pete Gillan present: **true**\n' +
  'Student num 2 Student name: John Reager present: true\n' +
  'Student num 3 Student name: Mary Smith present: false\n' +
  ' 6'
:~/roster-project/src/simple/assembly$
```

class:

```
import { logging, RNG } from "near-sdk-as";

//@nearBindgen
export class Student {

        private studnum: i32
        private sname: string;
        private present: boolean;

        constructor (studnum: i32, sname: string, present: boolean) {
            //studnum = this.studnum;
            //sname = this.sname;
            //present = this.present;

            this.sname = sname;
            this.studnum = studnum;
            this.present = present;

        }

        set_studnum(): void {
            this.studnum = studnum;
        }

        set_name(): void {

            this.sname = same;
        }

        set_present(): void {
            this.present = true;
        }

        set_absent(): void {
            this.present = false;

        }

        get_studnum(): i32 {
            return this.studnum;
        }

        get_sname(): string {
            return  this.sname;
        }

        get_present(): boolean {
            return this.present;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of flaws in the logic of your smart contract.

You declare 3 objects and then save these objects in a PersistentVector. After that, you modify one of the original objects (not the one saved in the PersistentVector) and then you print the objects.

In near you have 2 "feature" to save data, Store or Persistent collections.
If you want to save the state of a class, you have to use one of those functions (e.g. the PersistentVector).

A class is not a persistent object, so it won't be saved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this helps, but in your `absent` method, you could try to get a student from your `PersistentVector`, `currstudents`. Because `myStudent0` is a different object than what's stored in `currstudents`.

I find that I need to get the object from the list, make a change, and then add it back in.

Just a note:
When using the singleton pattern (not the same you are using), we sometimes need to add the `@mutateState()` decorator to the function if we change a state in the class itself. I don't think we need it in your case though, since the students are in a `PersistentVector` to begin with.

```ws
// @mutateState() decorator only needed if you change the state of the class
export function absent(): string{
    // mystudent0.set_absent();
    const student = currstudents[0];
    student.set_absent();
    currstudents[0] = student; // actually overwrites the student.
    return "absent";
}
```